# How can i add values from the front end to a json file in a react application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have built a react application where I have created a file upload mechanism. Now along with the file upload there are three dropdowns 'Controller','Test' and 'Protocol'. Now along with the file upload to the server functionality I am enabling the user to add the values to the dropdown from the front-end itself. I have enforced few validations on the file which is getting uploaded and then

I am adding the controller, test and protocol based on the file name. SO for instance if the filename of the uploaded file is "abc_xyz_sas_uut.config" which is the variable Filename in the script then the three fields 'Controller','Test' and 'Protocol' should only accept 'abc','xyz' and 'sas' as the respective values.

I have written the below script but its getting me an error 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'. The problem is I guess that its setting the status twice. Can anyone help to fix this issue, any help is greatly appreciated as I am stuck at this point.

```
    class FileUpload extends Component {
      state = {
        file: "",
        fileName: "Choose File",
        uploadDisabled: true,
        controller: "",
        test: "",
        protocol: "",
      };
      handleFileChange = (e) => {
        let index = e.target.files[0].name.search(/\w+[_]\w+[_]\w+[_]uut.yaml-example/i);
        if (index === 0) {
          this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });
          this.setState({ fileName: e.target.files[0].name });
          this.setState({ uploadDisabled: false });
        } else {
          window.alert(
            "File name or format is not correct ! \nCorrect format is controller_test_protocol_uut.yaml-example"
          );

        }
        e.target.value = null;
      };
      handleUpload = async (e) => {
        console.log("Starting upload");
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", this.state.file);
        formData.append("controller", this.state.controller);
        formData.append("test", this.state.test);
        formData.append("protocol", this.state.protocol);

        try {
          const res = await axios.post(this.props.url + "/upload", formData, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          });

          const { status } = res.data;
          if (status === "ok") {
            this.props.refreshOptions();
            this.setState({ file: "" });
            this.setState({ fileName: "Choose File" });
            this.setState({controller : ""});
            this.setState({test : ""});
            this.setState({protocol : ""});
            alert("File Uploaded Successfully");
            document.getElementById("closeButton").click();
          }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err); 
        }
      };
 handleTextChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `res.json()` statement in your `else`-block:

```
//Writing Config back to disk
}
else {
    res.json({
        status: "Invalidvalues"
    });
}
```

and right after

```
res.json({
    status: "ok"
});
```

So in case of hitting the else block `res.json()` is executed twice which is probably the cause for the error. You should change the statement in the else block to:

```
return res.json({
    status: "Invalidvalues"
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response. That's what my confusion is, where should I put res.json({status: "ok"}). The use case is, if the file is valid and the file name and text options (controller,test and protocol) are same then the file will get successfully uploaded.

Comment: Can't you just move it up into the `if`-block after doing `fs.writeFileSync(...)`?

Comment: Also you should maybe try to extract one or more methods from that handler - I think it would greatly increase the readability of your code :)

Comment: oh yes it worked now. Can you help me with one more thing though. I am trying to refresh the fields after status is received by the server. I have attached the front end code as well. The file state is getting refreshed properly but the other three fields are not getting refreshed

Comment: Hmm honestly I have to admit I'm not really a frontend-guy, maybe it's better to accept and close this question and create a new question regarding the frontend :)

Comment: @Jayashri: Could you please accept my answer? Thank you :)